# Google Sheets QR code "tab"

Tags: google-sheets, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am working with the Google sheets to make QR codes. I have my scanner programmed to do a 'TAB' function after every scan and it works well. I would like to make a single QR code that has 3 different pieces of information in it with a tab between each and an enter on the end. I have tried many ways and just found that most of them work fine in something like Notepad, but nothing is working in a form where there are 3 fields. The form has the following fields: Plant, Department, Part#
I have tried using:

```
//cell E12 has 106+%09+W6311A+%09+12345678 or 106+char(9)+W6311A+char(9)+12345678
=if(isblank(E12),"",image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&E12))

//A14==106, B14==W06311A, C14==12345678
=CONCATENATE(A14, char(9),B14,char(9),C14,char(10))
//A15==the above concatenate code
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl="& urlencode(join(char(10),arrayformula(A15))))

//this script is called by the above code:
/**
 * Converts a string to a properly encoded URI
 *
 * @param {string}  component  The component you want to encode
 * @return {string}            The encoded URI component.
 * @customfunction
 */
function urlencode ( component ) {
    if ( component && component.map ) {
    return component.map ( urlencode );
    Logger.log(component);
  }
  else {
    return encodeURIComponent ( component || "" ) ;
    Logger.log("2 "+component);
  }

}
```

As I said, they work fine in word or notepad, but they put all the information into one field of a form. One scan could be quicker then the current 3 individual scans that we do. Is there a coding method that is specific to fill in forms?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: What model of barcode scanner and how is it connected to the system, e.g. keyboard wedge, USB keyboard emulation, custom driver, integrated app, ...?

Comment: Please include an example image generated by the Google Charts API for the included code.

Comment: Here is the scanner: http://www.barcodeplanet.com/motorola/part-ds3578-dp2f005wr.htm ... and here is the scan: https://drive.google.com/a/nexteer.com/file/d/0B2rmtcQKIAZ2enZxeFV1dzBtaUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is a quick video, no sound, but the program I used added keystroke sounds when I used the scanner. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2rmtcQKIAZ2NzA0MEtYblk1Vjk2ZWJaandzUjh4MVVvUGUw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So it's a Bluetooth interface which could mean either keyboard emulation or some kind of custom channel. (Think of this as the difference between you typing individual characters vs pasting a clipboard buffer.) Interestingly the characters appear slowly suggesting keyboard emulation but in this case I would expect the form input to work. Does the device have any configurable input modes? If not it will be difficult to determine what is going on remotely.

Comment: As I mentioned, the software I used to record my screen made it look like I typed the information in even though I used the scanner. It does populate faster then in the video. The scanner's charging base that it is paired to is plugged into my computer via USB and the scanner talks to that by Bluetooth. Under the 'Set Up Interface' section it is currently set as "HID Keyboard Emulation." I tried it as "IBM Hand-Held USB" and it didn't input anything to the computer.

Comment: I see at the bottom of the sheet that it has options for 'Radio Communications Host Types'. I haven't changed that selection and I am not sure what the default one is. The options there are "Cradle Host", "Serial Port Profile (Slave)", "Bluetooth Keyboard Emulation (HID Slave)", and "Serial Port Profile (Master)"      I know how to program the scanner itself to do a carriage return or TAB, but I can't have it do that every time, sometimes I need a tab and other times I need an enter so I wanted to put it into my the scan information